# Order of promise wrong

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to return a list of promises with Promise.all, but the result is always empty.

Here is my theoric code:

```
function myFunction() {

    const pSqlLines = sql.openDatabase().then(mdb => {
        const query = `SELECT data FROM database`
        return mdb.prepare(query).all()
    })

    
    const globalPromise = new Promise( resolve => {

        const promises = []
        pSqlLines.then( sqlLines => {

            sqlLines.forEach(line => {
                promiseA()
                .then(res1 => { if (res1 == 1) return promiseB() }) 
                .then(res2 => { if (res2 == 1) return promiseC() }) 
                .then(res3 => { if (res3 == 1) promises.push( new Promise(resolve => resolve(line) ) ) })                
            }) // The promises chaining is correct as the 'promises' array is correctly fulfilled, but later

            resolve( Promise.all(promises) ); // It is always called before the foreach loop. Why?
        })
    })

    return globalPromise.then( result => console.log(result) )
}
```

Someone can help me please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `async` and `await`, otherwise it will always execute first.

Comment: What is the sense of  `if (res1 == 1)`? What if this is false, what do you expect the changed `then` callback to work with?

Comment: `Promise.all(promises)` will always use an empty array for `promises`, because nothing makes the code wait for the array to be filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to create a new promise with `new Promise` when you already have a promise to work with -- in your case: `pSqlLines`. Wrapping `pSqlLines` inside a `new Promise` wrapper is an example of the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Secondly, this code:

```
 new Promise(resolve => resolve(line) )
```

...can be replaced with:

```
 Promise.resolve(line)
```

...and since it is to serve as the return value for a `then` callback, it can be just:

```
 line
```

As to your question: you are indeed calling `Promise.all(promises)` at a moment that the `promises` array is still empty, as the `forEach` loop has only executed `Promise()` and its `then` chain, but none of the asynchronous callbacks that are passed to those `then` calls have executed yet. You didn't await the resolution of these promises.

I get from your code that you want to exclude some `line` values depending on conditions. In that case the promise will resolve to `undefined`. I suppose you would want to exclude those `undefined` values, and so maybe a `filter(Boolean)` is appropriate.

Here is a theoretical solution for your theoretical code:

```
function myFunction() {
    const pSqlLines = sql.openDatabase().then(mdb => {
        const query = `SELECT data FROM database`;
        return mdb.prepare(query).all();
    });
    
    return pSqlLines.then( sqlLines => {
        const promises = sqlLines.map(line => {
            return promiseA()
                .then(res1 => { if (res1 == 1) return promiseB(); }) 
                .then(res2 => { if (res2 == 1) return promiseC(); }) 
                .then(res3 => { if (res3 == 1) return line; });
        }));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(result => result.filter(Boolean));
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `== 1` might not even be needed but I don't know what it actually checks for. At the very least, maybe there is a different way to verify things that is more descriptive.

Comment: I asked the OP for clarification 5 minutes after they posted, but no reaction so far. I guess this is part of what they call "theoretic code".

Comment: @trincot: Sorry for the late answer as I am trying your improvement code and it works perfectly! It seems very simple as you write :) The filter function will reduce others code I wrote. Thank you a lot for the tip.